# pandas manual way of one hot encode

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as given below and trying to convert one hot encode it (kind of)

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {0: {0: 'eng', 1: 'eng', 2: 'mat', 3: 'fre', 4: 'soc', 5: 'eng',
         6: 'eng', 7: 'mat', 8: 'fre', 9: 'soc'},
     1: {0: 'mat', 1: 'phy', 2: 'bio', 3: 'phy', 4: 'mat', 5: 'mat',
         6: 'phy', 7: 'bio', 8: 'mat', 9: 'mat'},
     2: {0: 'che', 1: 'che', 2: None, 3: 'soc', 4: 'lit', 5: 'che',
         6: 'che', 7: None, 8: 'eng', 9: 'lit'},
     3: {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None,
         6: None, 7: None, 8: 'phy', 9: None}})
```

resultant output I am require is

| eng | mat | che | phy | lit | fre | soc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I need to do it without using any libraries except pandas, any idea how I can do it?

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear. You should explain what one-hot encoding is, or at the very least provide a link to an explanation—and then you need to explain how what you are trying to do is *kind of* one-hot encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) on the stacked DataFrame, then get the max per level 0:

```
(pd
 .get_dummies(df.stack())
 .groupby(level=0)
 .max()
 )
```

Another approach is to `stack` to Series and use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
s = df.stack()
pd.crosstab(s.index.get_level_values(0), s).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

Output:

```
   bio  che  eng  fre  lit  mat  phy  soc
0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0
1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0
2    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
3    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    1
4    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1
5    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0
6    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0
7    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
8    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    0
9    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1
```